# How to implement a taxonomy view?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I would like to show a list of taxonomy terms and include:

- number of nodes that are linked to this term
- datestamp of latest node with author and title that is linked to this term

Can this be done in a view, or do I need a custom query?
From a performance standpoint, wouldn't it be better to save that info in taxonomy fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to create a **View** using grouping.

Set **Format** to ***Table*** 
Go to **Settings** > ***Grouping field*** = "***Tags***" (your taxonomy term field)

Field "Tag" should have this setting:

- Exclude from display [X]

There are some modules I didn't try that could help you with adding summary field to your Views:

- **[Views PHP](http://drupal.org/project/views_php)** (D6 + D7) or **[Views Custom Field](http://drupal.org/project/views_customfield)** (D6)
- **[Views Calc](http://drupal.org/project/views_calc)** (D6) or **[Computed Field](http://drupal.org/project/computed_field)** (D7)
- **[Views Group By](http://drupal.org/project/views_groupby)** (D6)
- **[Views Summarize](http://drupal.org/project/views_summarize)** (D6)
- **[Views Hacks](http://drupal.org/project/views_hacks)** (D6) (including **Views Taxonomy Summary**)
- Views Taxonomy Edge + **[Taxonomy Edge](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_edge)** (D6 + D7)
- **[Better Exposed Filters](http://drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters)** (D6 + D7)
- **[Taxonomy Views Integrator](http://drupal.org/project/tvi)** (D6 + D7)

Comment: Maybe someone could explain which solution is faster and the best practice ?

Comment: There is an article "Best practice? Math expression fields, Computed Fields, Views Calc, hook_views_pre_render and more" on http://drupal.org/node/1219356